# Apply remap only on coordinates obtained from distorted image and not on whole image

Tags: c++, opencv

The initUndistortRectifyMap function in opencv results in maap in x and y direction that contains the coordinates of the undistorted pixel it computes these maps based on intrinsic camera matrix ,distortion matrix and rotation matrix.

```
initUndistortRectifyMap(cam1,dst1,R1,P1, imageSize, CV_16SC2, map1x,map1y);
```

cam1 (intrinsic camera matrix)
dst1 (distortion coefficients)
R1 (Rotation Matrix)
map1x (new map of size of the image to denote where the shifted x coordinate lies in undistorted image)
map2x ((new map of size of the image to denote where the shifted y coordinate lies in undistorted image)
So if new the image coordinates in distorted image (xdistort,ydistort)
the undistorted can be computed using

```
x_undistort = map1x.at<short>(ydistort,xdistort);
y_undistort = map2x.at<short>(ydistort,xdistort);
```

I checked the corresponding points in undistorted image they donot result in the same point. I checked the value of map1x at (0,0) and it contains negative value and when I click on console to find the coordinate value it gives the corresponding result from (0:im_width,0:imheight) . Is there any normalization procedure ? How to compute points directly without processing the whole image .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates of a pixel are integer numbers. So getting them as floating points numbers is pointless.

If you need `Point2f`, you can simply construct a `Point2f` from the retrieved `Point`:

```
double minVal; double maxVal; Point minLoc; Point maxLoc;
minMaxLoc( result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat() );

Point2f minLocF(minLoc);
Point2f maxLocF(maxLoc);
```

If you need a function with that signature, you can apply this in a wrapper function, or change OpenCV source code and recompile (not recommended).

Comment: I need subpixel accuracy in Localization and there are many algorithms developed to achieve the same so I don't agree if it is pointless .

Comment: Sure, but `minMaxLoc` doesn't use subpixel accuracy. So overloading it **is** pointless. If you want to search something with subpixel accuracy, you have to do it yourself. However, I fail to see how getting the maximum value pixel can be done with subpixel accuracy

Comment: Yes , I get your point . Actually I'm using that value further to compute some averaging but I agree minmax function won't do any subpixel computation and return float value anyway.Thanks, for a quick response