# Compute coordinates of transformed bounding box corners in an image rectified by OpenCV remap

Tags: opencv, remap, fisheye

I am computing bounding boxes for objects in an image taken with a 180deg fisheye lens. These bounding boxes will sometimes trigger an event that requires a rectified image. To rectify the image, I am currently using OpenCV's `remap` with maps precomputed by `initUndistortRectifyMap`:

```
map1, map2 = cv2.fisheye.initUndistortRectifyMap(K, D, np.eye(3), P, DIM, cv2.CV_16SC2)
undistorted_img = cv2.remap(img, map1, map2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
```

The following are the parameters used:

```
K = [[169.53432726   0.         322.5714669 ]
     [  0.         169.39413982 289.12455088]
     [  0.           0.           1.        ]]
D = [[ 0.11919361]
     [ 0.29904975]
     [-0.20295709]
     [ 0.05526085]]
P = [[121.41853905   0.         322.57040373]
     [  0.         121.31813842 289.11177491]
     [  0.           0.           1.        ]]
DIM = (640, 640)
```

**Is there a simple, efficient way to compute the coordinates of the bounding box corners in the rectified image (given precomputed maps for x and y)?**

1. I believe [this unanswered post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57352239/can-get-specify-points-coordinate-from-output-image-using-opencv-remap) may have been wondering the same thing.
2. I also think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23929365/how-to-get-original-position-of-a-pixel-after-a-remap-in-opencv) was trying to ask a similar question, but it's not clear how to apply the answer to my question (Caveat #1: if the "inverse" map can be used to map a point in the distorted image to a point in the undistorted image, then great--but not clear how to do that from the answer; Caveat #2: it's not clear the inverse map is available for the fisheye module).
3. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35690659/apply-remap-only-on-coordinates-obtained-from-distorted-image-and-not-on-whole-i?rq=2) is also relevant--again, not clear to me that it actually answers the question, though
4. I have attempted to invert `map1` using the iterative algorithm proposed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72635492/what-are-the-inaccuracies-of-this-inverse-map-function-in-opencv), but the algorithm does not seem to converge on a useful inverse map. Instead, it returns negative and enormous coordinate values, which are self-evidently incorrect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the inaccuracies of this 'inverse map' function in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72635492/what-are-the-inaccuracies-of-this-inverse-map-function-in-opencv)

Comment: given it's a fisheye, it doesn't map lines to lines, so you'll have to map every point along your box, not just the corners. -- the fisheye model itself ***should*** give you methods to map points from rectified to fisheye and back. one of those directions may involve a few iterations to converge, which is implied and hidden from you in the method. -- I *did not check* if OpenCV has any methods to generate the *other map* given a fisheye model, the one that warps straight to fisheye. it might.

Comment: if all you have is a plain LUT for remap(), it performs an inverse lookup, i.e. destination coordinates to source coordinates. you can try to invert it numerically. then you can map source coordinates to destination coordinates. the [answer I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72635492/what-are-the-inaccuracies-of-this-inverse-map-function-in-opencv) demonstrates numeric inversion and uses theory from [an earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703210/inverting-a-real-valued-index-grid/68706787#68706787)

Comment: please add detail about your fisheye model. if you can, post all the numbers quantifying your model fit. example input data would also help. [mre]

Comment: Thanks @ChristophRackwitz. I only require the corners--I understand that it does not map lines to lines.

If it's possible to compute an inverse map offline, and then use that on the fly, it should be a constant time lookup :). I'll take a look at what you've linked.

Comment: As an aside @ChristophRackwitz, I was expecting the returned maps (`map1` and `map2` above) to have dimensions (w,h) with the first sending x',y' -> x and the second sending x',y' -> y, but in fact `map1` has dimensions (w,h,2) and `map2` has dimensions (w,h). Have I misunderstood what `initUndistortRectifyMap` returns? Fwiw, I'm using 3-channel RGB images with dimensions (w,h,3)

Comment: I assume that `map1` is the lookup table, and I've used that for trying to iteratively compute the inverse map. The resulting inverse map does not seem to converge, and the result is nonsensical (it contains negative pixel coordinates and pixel coordinates an order of magnitude greater than the image dimensions)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256856/discussion-between-mackie-messer-and-christoph-rackwitz).

Comment: if you have "weird" maps (16SC2 for integer coordinate parts and 16UC1 for packed fractional parts), they're probably the fixed point arithmetic kind. conceptually doesn't matter, implementation detail. `convertMaps` has some details but not all details.

Comment: there is `fisheye::distortPoints` and `fisheye::undistortPoints`. I don't see the issue.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks. I saw those, but the discussions I found suggested it was inefficient for whatever reason. That's part of the reason why I was wondering specifically if there were any way to use precomputed maps from `iniUndistortRectifyMap`

Comment: Inverting the LUT (or analogous approaches) can be done offline, providing a constant-time look-up at runtime for any program that utilizes the inverse table. In my case, the computation is applied several times per frame of a live video stream.